# Mails are not being sent

Tags: oop, php

I am running my testing for this website on a [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server). The mail function is currently not sending any emails. It could be a code error or I could possibly not be seeing something in my code.

If someone could maybe look and tell me what I am doing wrong. I am not sure if something is odd with my code or it is my VPS. I have sent emails using my VPS before, and it has worked on other sites, so I am not sure why this is not working.

#### Mail.php

```
class Mail {

    protected $to;
    protected $title;
    protected $email;
    protected $fullName;
    protected $company;
    protected $enquiry;
    protected $message;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->email = $_POST['email'];
        $this->fullName = $_POST['fullName'];
        $this->company = $_POST['company'];
        $this->enquiry = $_POST['enquiry'];
        return;
    }

    function setToTitle($to, $title) {
        $this->to = $to;
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    function getToTitle() {
        return $this->to;
        return $this->title;
    }

    function setMessage($message) {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    function getMessage() {
        return $this->message;
    }

    function setEmail($email) {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    function setFullName($fullName) {
        $this->fullName = $fullName;
    }

    function setCompany($company) {
        $this->company = $company;
    }

    function setEnquiry($enquiry) {
        $this->enquiry = $enquiry;
    }

    function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    function getFullName() {
        return $this->fullName;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the email
     */
    function sendMail() {
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
        $headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8";
        $headers[] = "From: testing <test@test.com>";
        $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
        mail($this->to, $this->title, $this->getMessage(), implode("\r\n", $headers));
    }

    /**
     * Sends a product enquiry email
     * Automatically sets the to address, title and content
     */
    function sendContactEmail() {
        $this->to = $this->getEmail();
        $this->title = 'Semtronics Product Enquiry';
        $s = 'Hello, ' . $this->getFullName();
        $s .= "\nThank you for your product enquiry, we will contact you as soon as possible.";
        $s .= "\nKind Regards,";
        $s .= "\nTest Team";
        $this->message = $s;
        $this->sendMail();
    }
```

#### Controller.php

```
class Controller {

    protected $loginHandler;
    protected $view;

    function __construct() {
        $this->loginHandler = new LoginHandler();
    }

    function getLoginHandler() {
        return $this->loginHandler;
    }
}
```

#### ContactPageController.php:

```
class ContactPageController extends Controller {

    function invoke() {
        if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
            $action = $_GET['action'];
            if ($action == 'contactUs') {
                return $this->sendContactEnquiry();
            }
        }
        $view = new ContactPageView($this);
        $view->display();
    }

    function sendContactEnquiry() {

        // Validate full name
        if (!isset($_POST['fullName']) || $_POST['fullName'] == '') {
            $this->view = new ContactPageView($this);
            $this->view->display('Please enter your full name.');
            return;
        }

        // Validate email
        if (!isset($_POST['email']) || $_POST['email'] == '') {
            $this->view = new ContactPageView($this);
            $this->view->display('Please enter your email address.');
            return;
        }

        // Validate enquiry
        if (!isset($_POST['enquiry']) || $_POST['enquiry'] == '') {
            $this->view = new ContactPageView($this);
            $this->view->display('Please fill out your enquiry.');
            return;
        }

        $mail = new Mail();
        $mail->sendContactEmail();
        var_dump($mail);
        $this->view = new ContactPageView($this);
        $this->view->display('Thank you for your enquiry!');
    }
}
```

#### ContactPageView.php:

```
class ContactPageView extends View {

    function display($error = null) {

        include APPROOT . 'include/formHelpers.php';

        $title = 'Contact Us';
        $body = 'contactpage.php';

        include(HTMLROOT . 'page.php');
    }
}
```

#### contactpage.php:

```
<section class="contact-container left s-container">
    <div class="center">
        <h2>Product Enquiry</h2>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(SITEROOT . '?location=contact&action=contactUs'); ?>">
        <?php if (isset($error)): ?>
            <div class="error">
                <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($error); ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
            <label for="fullName">Full Name<input type="text" name="fullName" id="fullName" ></label>
            <label for="email">Email<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="someone@example.com" ></label>
            <label for="company">Company (Optional)<input type="text" name="company" id="company" ></label>
            <label for="enquiry">Enquiry<textarea name="enquiry" rows="10" cols="50" id="enquiry" placeholder="What would you like to know?" ></textarea></label>
            <input class="btn-blue" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Enquiry">
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Consider a [search like this](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=How+do+I+prevent+email+being+detected+as+spam%3F) - the top result is a Stack Exchange site, so should have some good answers.

Comment: As far as I remember, the mails sent by `mail()` does not include an authentication header therefore are considered as spam by most mail hosts (gmail, etc).

Comment: There is so much that could be wrong to begin with. It could be the code. Maybe your sendmail/postfix or PHP installation is not configured correctly. Just tail the logs and try to figure out where things get messed up. Did you test it locally? Did it work then?

Comment: Did not work locally no, it does not error code wise, i fixed all errors, var dumps show all post data been grabbed correctly, i cant see why else i would not receive the email, even my spam folder is empty, so it is not sending at all

Comment: Like @Bart said, maybe you could get something in the log. Try `$res = mail(...); var_dump($res);` and see if you are getting a true or false in `$res`.

Comment: returns bool(true) object(Mail)

Comment: Checking the return value of `mail()` is not recommended. It will not indicate the message is sent. Check the logs of your mail program e.g. sendmail or postfix. If they show you nothing it must be a php.ini configuration or something.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to replace native `mail()` with some other sophisticated tool like **[PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer)**.

**Some benefits:**

1. Less code
2. Easy maintenance
3. More features (HTML mails, etc.)
4. It uses your [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol)/[POP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) mail servers. So there is less chance of ending up in spam!